# Insert multirows from checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this post request:

```
"schedule":{
    "available_datetime":["1","4","10"],
    "booked_datetime":"2"
},
```

Now I want for each `available_datetime` to create a row in db with same `today` param.
Here is how I am trying:

```
def create

  @params =  params[:schedule]
  @array = []
  @params[:available_datetime].each do |schedule| 
      @schedule = Schedule.new()
      @schedule.teacher_id = current_user.id
      @schedule.available_datetime = schedule
      @schedule.booked_datetime = @params[:booked_datetime]
      
      @array.push(@schedule)
  end  

  render json:  @array
end
```

It's giving me

```
[
{"id":null,"teacher_id":"2""available_datetime":null,"booked_datetime":null},
{"id":null,"teacher_id":"2","available_datetime":null,"booked_datetime":null},
{"id":null,"teacher_id":"2","available_datetime":"2020-12-10T00:00:00.000Z","booked_datetime":null}
]
```

Comment: Doesn't matter. All I want is to add rows based on available_datetime items, in fact I can with `@schedule.save` but `booked_datetime` is being null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20963556/477902 this helped to achieve

Comment: from the result you get, and from the identifiers you use, availavable_datetime and booked_datetime seem to be of type datetime. So, what would you expect as a result when assigning a value of "1", "4" or "10" to a datetime attribute? Rails has a habit of failing graciously when it cannot understand assigned values, resulting in hard to track bus. Can you confirm what the types of these fields are? Any validations in place? What is the errors attribute on the new records when you call valid?

Comment: @AndreasGebhard thats exactly what happened when i changed to datetime worked, but not very good error description